# Can BlocBuilder of flutter_bloc avoid rebuild part of Widget which not changing?

Tags: flutter, bloc

`BlocBuilder` of [`flutter_bloc`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) is kind of put all state of page together.

There's a case for `pulling a list` there's 2 data (`isPullingState`, `dataList`), how can I avoid build widget part of dataList when `dataList` not change, but build  widget part of `isPullingState` which changed from **true** to **false** ?

`BlocBuilderCondition` looks like only avoid rebuild when hole state not change.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `BlocBuilder` have a optinal parameter `condition` that have type `bool Function(State previous, State current)`, you need to return `true` if you want the widget call the `builder` function, and `false` if you don't want. This parameter is optional, and by default is `true`.

Because the in the `condition` parameter you have the `previous` state and the `current` state you can compare the properties of this states and and return `true` if it satisfies your comparisons.

Remember that you need to override the  `==` operator and `hashCode` of your state and all classes that use in your state class. And easy way to do this is using [equatable](https://github.com/felangel/equatable).

In your case you need to have a `State` like this:

```dart
class MyState extends Equatable {
  final bool isPullingState;
  final List<MyClass> dataList;

  MyState(this.isPullingState, this.dataList)
      : super([isPullingState, dataList]);
}

class MyClass extends Equatable {
  final int property1;
  final int property2;

  MyClass(this.property1, this.property2)
      : super([
          property1,
          property2,
        ]);
}
```

And then in your widget you can set the condition that you want:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        BlocBuilder(
          bloc: myBloc,
          condition: (MyState previous, MyState current) =>
              previous.isPullingState != current.isPullingState,
          builder: (BuildContext context, MyState state) {
            // this function is only called when isPullingState change
            return MyIsPullingWidget();
          },
        ),
        BlocBuilder(
          bloc: myBloc,
          condition: (MyState previous, MyState current) =>
              previous.dataList != current.dataList,
          builder: (BuildContext context, MyState state) {
            // this function is only called when the dataList change
            return MyListWidget(state.dataList);
          },
        ),
        BlocBuilder(
          bloc: myBloc,
          builder: (BuildContext context, MyState state) {
            // this function is called in each state change
            return MyListWidget(state.dataList);
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```